# Issue saving plots and text together to a word doc in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Am fairly new to the python world.
Am trying to save/print the output of my SARIMAX model to a word document, and it seems, I cannot save or print the plots/figures in the word doc.
Some of the text lines do get printed in the word doc, but not the plots.
Can you please advise where I am going wrong:

```
AIC = []

ar = [0,1,2,3,4]

for ar in ar:
    ma = [0,1,2,3,4]
for ma in ma:
    SDIFF = ['True','False']
    for sd in SDIFF:
        try:


       model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data, order=(ar,0,ma), seasonal_order=(ar,0,ma,1), simple_differencing=sd)
        result = model.fit()
    except:
        with open('file.doc', 'a') as f:
            print('Time Run:', str(datetime.now()), file = f)
            print('ar=',ar, 'ma=',ma, 'sd=',sd, file = f)
            #Result.append(result)
            print(result.summary(), file = f)   
            AIC.append(result.aic)
            data_fcpred = result.predict(start = 16, end = 18, dynamic= True) 
            print(plt.plot(data_fcpred , color = 'red'), file = f)
            print(plt.plot(data), file = f)
            print(result.plot_diagnostics(), file = f)
            print(plt.show(), file = f)
            print('AIC', result.aic, file = f)
            print(data[15:], file = f)         
            print(data_fcpred, file = f)
            plt.clf()
            print("#############################################", file = f)
            print("#######################################", file = f)
            continue
```

I can do a plt.savefig, however it saves to a different file as per the name that I have to specify in the savefig method.

What I really need is the plotting of the figures in the same word doc.

Comment: Are you aware of the [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library? It is very easy to print whatever your want i.e text, tables, images in a word document by using it. It has also very good documentation. Have a look at it.

Comment: Hi Nikos,
Yes not very familiar but aware of python-x.
The challenge in my case (could also be because of my lack of expertise) is  creating images on the fly and saving them in the doc.
The python-docx is seen picking images from the disk.